# Retain same array key value rest other delete in php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have below PHP array

```
Array
(
    [attendees] => Array
        (
            [322] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [attendee_name] => Amy Rainwater
                            [attendee_email] => arainwater@azdps.gov
                            [attendee_phone] => 345676575
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [attendee_name] => Lisa Hernandez
                            [attendee_email] => lhernandez@azdps.gov
                            [attendee_phone] => 34565
                        )

                )

        )

    [registration] => Array
        (
            [user_name] => Amy Rainwater
            [user_email] => arainwater@azdps.gov
            [dbem_name] => Lisa Hernandez
            [dbem_email] => lhernandez@azdps.gov
            [dbem_address] => PO Box 6638
            [dbem_phone] => 343545546
            [dbem_city] => Ph
            [dbem_state] => Arz
            [dbem_zip] => 85334
            [dbem_company] => Arizona Department of Public Safety
        )

    [gateway] => authorize_aim
)
```

I want to retain [attendees] [322] [0] this key value rest other [1] remove from the attendees array. Currently you can see there is three arrays. So in first array (attendees) we have value "amy rainwater" so I want to retain this key value and other key value i.e [0]->Lisa Hernandez this sholud be removed from there. So please confrim how can I filter this array.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried `unset()`?

Comment: yes I have used unset function but i want to remove other key value i.e [1]=>lisa

Comment: If I used unset($res_booking_meta['attendees'][322][0]) then it will remove   index key [0] value i.e amy rainwater but I need to remove [1] key value i.e lisa

Comment: then use `unset($res_booking_meta['attendees'][322][1])`

Comment: but this key is dynamic when i clicked on amy rainwater then i have fetched key value of i.e [0] not [1]. so I want to retain only this value[0] not [1] by dynamic key variable.

Comment: Resolved now!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php):

```
reset($res_booking_meta['attendees'][322]);
```